# Calculate PI in Java. Wrong value

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate PI using the `Gregory-Leibniz` algorithm but I'm always getting wrong values only using multi-threading. Single thread works fine.

I think the issue is the `k` value that is shared and the calculation messes up.

**Wrong PI Value:**

> Select an option: 4 How many points? 100000 How many threads? 32
>   Concurrent Gregory-Leibniz estimated PI value : 2.7663972054374577.
>   Executed in 121.578657 ms.

Any help please?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * The Class GregoryLeibniz.
 */
public class GregoryLeibniz {

    /** The in circle. */
    private double factor;

    /** The sum. */
    private double sum;

    /** The points. */
    private long points;

    /** The n processors. */
    private int nProcessors;

    private long k;


    /**
     * Instantiates a new gregory leibniz.
     *
     * @param points the points
     * @param nProcessors the n processors
     */
    public GregoryLeibniz(long points, int nProcessors) {
        super();
        this.points = points;
        this.nProcessors = nProcessors;
    }


    /**
     * The Class GregoryLeibnizImpl.
     */
    public class GregoryLeibnizImpl implements Runnable {   

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(k % 2 == 0) factor = 1.0;
            else factor = -1.0;

            sum += factor / (2*k +1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate PI.
     *
     * @return the double
     */
    public double calculatePI() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(nProcessors);

        for (k = 0; k < points; k++) {
            Runnable worker = new GregoryLeibnizImpl();
            executor.execute(worker);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        while(!executor.isTerminated()) { }

        return 4.0 * sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you think that k is the problem try replacing it with an atomic long which will make sure each value is used only once. In general shared mutable variables are a *very* bad idea.

Comment: long story short: your code is missing synchronization, e.g. `+=` is not an atomic operation. You may want to take a look at the [`atomic` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) for a start.

Comment: Are you sure`k` and `factor` should be shared variables?

Comment: and `k` should be a field of the `Impl` class, that is, passed in the constructor and stored as field, since each probably should have its own value; and `factor` should be a method variable, only used locally; finally access to `sum` needs synchronization (or just be stored for each thread, and summed by main thread)

Comment: You have the classical example of a race condition. For calculations your should give a range for each worker and sum the results. Also when spitting the rangers a care must be taken to keep the precision

Comment: Guys, using an atomic number for k and sum without fixing the code will effectively serialize the calculation ,defeating the point of having multiple threads. In top of that, the synchronization overhead will be so severe that might be much worse than a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

Each instance of GregoryLeibnizImpl needs to be operating independently.  Or you need a mutex. Or both.

1. GregoryLeibnizImpl needs to take "k" as a constructor parameter and store it as member variable.
2. You need a mutex/guard around `sum`. Otherwise, you need to "sum up" all the results of the worker thread objects at the end of the `calculatePI` function.

This line:

```
while(!executor.isTerminated()) { }
```

Will burn an entire core and kill the performance of your code.  Use the [awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method instead.

**Update**

I wanted some practice, so I restructured your code for a worthy solution. Perhaps I helps....

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * The Class GregoryLeibniz.
 */
public  class GregoryLeibniz {

    /** The n processors. */
    private int nProcessors;
    private long points;
    private long itemsPerThread;
    private long itemsInFirstThread;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new gregory leibniz.
     *
     * @param points the points
     * @param nProcessors the n processors
     */
    public GregoryLeibniz(long points, int nProcessors) {
        this.points = points;
        this.nProcessors = nProcessors;
        this.itemsPerThread = this.points / this.nProcessors;
        this.itemsInFirstThread += this.itemsPerThread + this.points - this.itemsPerThread * this.nProcessors;
    }


    /**
     * The Class GregoryLeibnizImpl.
     */
    public class GregoryLeibnizImpl implements Runnable {

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
         */

        long start;
        long end;
        public double result;

        public GregoryLeibnizImpl(long start, long end)
        {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int factor = ((start % 2)!=0) ? -1 : 1;
            for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {

                result += factor / (double)(i*2+1);
                factor *= -1;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculate PI.
     *
     * @return the double
     */
    public double calculatePI() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(nProcessors);

        long start = 1;
        long end = itemsInFirstThread;

        GregoryLeibnizImpl [] workers = new GregoryLeibnizImpl[this.nProcessors];

        for (int t = 0; t < this.nProcessors; t++) {
            GregoryLeibnizImpl worker = new GregoryLeibnizImpl(start, end);
            workers[t] = worker;
            executor.execute(worker);
            start += this.itemsPerThread;
            end += this.itemsPerThread;
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        while (executor.isTerminated() == false) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        double result = 0;
        for (int t = 0; t < this.nProcessors; t++) {
            result += workers[t].result;
        }

        result += 1;
        result *= 4;

        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        var gl = new GregoryLeibniz(1000000, 4);
        double d = gl.calculatePI();
        System.out.println(d);
    }

}
```

Comment: I did the 1. I don't understand how to the 2.

Comment: I did the mutex and it's even worse Concurrent Gregory-Leibniz estimated PI value : -0.06089736234327452. Executed in 6498.187793 ms.

Comment: Given the amount of code in your `run` function, the cost of spinning up a thread and taking a lock is more overhead than just running the code sequentially.  I would do this.  Rather than breaking up the algorithm into K threads, break the code up into N threads where N is the number of processors.  Each thread performs `K/N` calculations.  As for why you aren't getting a correct value - you should start by letting N be 1 and debug on that ,then scale to 2, 3, etc... all the way up to N.

Answer (score 0):

Try synchronise the run method. If you let k without mutex one thread will check modulus of k, set factor and then it will go asleep, and next thread will check modulus set (same) factor, do sum += stuff and go asleep. After that first thread will also do sum += stuff with old factor.

Comment: You cannot synchronize on primitives in Java. Also, `k` is not the only shared variable with multi-write access.

Comment: Too fast writing on my side. Ment one thing, wrote another. Thanks.^^

Comment: you did not understand the algorithm, `k` is a different value for each thread

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your worker a copy of `k`. Apart from that you aren't really winning a lot by letting your workers do only one step in the sum. You should create not more workers than you have CPU (cores) available and give each a portion of the sum to calculate.

Please also note that this still leaves you with a wrong `sum`, because if two workers read and write to it simultaneously, one of their results will be lost.

Have each worker maintain a private `sum` instead, then when they are all done, add their private sums together in the main thread.

Something like this:

```
public class GregoryLeibnizImpl implements Runnable {
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int sum;

    public GregoryLeibnizImpl(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // loop from start to end using your sum algorithm
    }
}
```

Then change your loop to something like this:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < points; k += points / numthreads) {
        Runnable worker = new GregoryLeibnizImpl(k, k + points / numthreads);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
```

You need to keep those worker instances somewhere, a list for example, so you can collect their results once done.

Comment: please help me.

Comment: If you are in danger call the authorities. If you mean help you with your question, that's what I just did. I am not sure how to respond to your comment.